# Why does my LiveUSB not work?

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

I'm trying to get a dual boot Win8 and Ubuntu on my Asus Vivobook.

I have disabled FastBoot, I disabled FastStartup.

I have set the boot sequence in the correct order (and that works)

I have have created a LiveUSB both with LinuxLive USB Creator and Universal USB Creator. I have tried Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Ubuntu 13.04.

I got to the GRUB, but when I click "Try Ubuntu", "Install Ubuntu" or "Check Disk for errors", my screen turns black the USB flickers for 2 seconds and then nothing. No Hard Drive action, no USB action nothing (waited for about 10 minutes).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different machine to isolate if its the computer or if its the USB disc?

If it happens on another machine then its the USB. Try installing it on the USB again.

If it doesn't run, try a different USB drive

Answer (score -1):

Win8 PC come with something called secure boot. Just disable it in your BIOS to let the PC boot from removable media.

Comment: It already booted GRUB, which shouldn't be possible with secure boot.